# AngularJS official tutorial, how to add object?

Tags: rest, angularjs

I'm kinda stuck at testing Restful model without server-side.
[In Google official tutorial step 11](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11)

They show real nicely how to get all the phone lists from a local `json` files using `get` method.
It is really nice and very simple, but they are lacking something very basic in this tutorial deleting/adding with `delete/post` methods.

I'm stuck right now because I cannot find a way to add/delete objects using `Restful` model without implementing server-side `DB`, of course not permanently just throughout the  application life.

Can someone give an example that's built on AngularJS official tutorial, how to implement a simple add of a phone `object`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Angular's $resource service.

[Documentation here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource/)

That contains a working example similar to what I think you're asking.

Comment: This does not answer my question, I cannot find there a way to do post/delete on a local `json`